# What is wrong with "had a tendency of changing"?

Tags: idioms

From the SAT:

> The famous filmmaker had a tendency **of changing** his recollections, perhaps out of boredom at having to tell interviewers the same story over and over.

They said that "of changing" was wrong. Could someone tell me what is wrong with it? I am guessing it is an idiom error "...tendency **to change**..." but am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Who said it is wrong and can you ask them why?

Comment: It was on the SAT in the sentence error section.

Comment: Google Books: [has a tendency **to change**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+a+tendency+to+change%22), 32,100 hits; [has a tendency **of changing**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+a+tendency+of+changing%22), 10 hits. That might not tell you *why* the second version is "wrong", but it should be enough to tell you *which version you should use.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Had a tendency" implies a past pattern of something, and
"changing" implies it's currently happening, while "change" is more of a time-neutral commodity. It sounds awkward, at least to me, and I believe "tendency of" is really never used it's supposed to be "tendency to".

Answer (score 1):

We say:

> The price of flights *tends to* increase around holidays.

Rewritten, casting the verb as a noun phrase:

> <sup>OK</sup> The price of flights has *a tendency to increase* around holidays.
>
> <sup>not OK</sup> The price of flights has *a tendency of increasing* around  holidays.

So, to figure out whether a given preposition works, find the verb that underlies the noun.

Comment: Is the verb that underlines the noun "increase" or "tends" in your example?

Comment: The verb is **tends**.   The wordier phrase using the noun is "has a tendency".